# how to take input text from alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form in which there are input fields for mobile number ,name and email.I have two buttons add and group.Add button  add new records of the selected records.Group button is used to create a group of selected fields on the records.So when you click on group button it will ask whether to create a group or not.If yes then it will create a group named as 0 or 1.But I want to give some name(user should type the name to be given) to the group.Please tell me how to do.This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/172/) and this is the screenshot

This is the jquery

```
var val = 0;
var groupTrCount = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj={};
    $('#btn1').click(function () {
        if ($(".span4").val() != "") {
            $("#mytable").append('<tr id="mytr' + val + '"></tr>');
            $tr=$("#mytr" + val);
            $tr.append('<td class=\"cb\"><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"yes\" name="mytr' + val + '" checked ></td>');
            $(".span4").each(function () {
                $tr.append("<td >" + $(this).val() + "</td>");
            });
            var arr={};
            name=($tr.find('td:eq(1)').text());
            email=($tr.find('td:eq(2)').text());
            mobile=($tr.find('td:eq(3)').text());
            arr['name']=name;arr['email']=email;arr['mobile']=mobile;
            obj[val]=arr;
            val++;
        } else {
            alert("please fill the form completely");
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#btn2',function () {
        var creat_group = confirm("Do you want to creat a group??");
        if (creat_group) {
            console.log(obj);

            $("#groupsTable").append('<tr id="groupTr' + groupTrCount + '"></tr>');
            $tr=$("#groupTr" + groupTrCount);
            $tr.append("<td >" + groupTrCount + "</td>");
            var userColumn = "<ul>";
            $('#mytable tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
                var count=0;
                $(this).find('td').each(function() {
                    if(count == 1){

                        userColumn+= "<li>" + $(this).html() + "</li>" ;
                    }
                    count++;
                    });
            });
            userColumn+="<ul>";
            $tr.append("<td >" +userColumn+ "</td>");
        groupTrCount++;
        }        
    });
    $(document).on('change','#mytable input:checkbox',function () {
        if(!this.checked)
        {
            key=$(this).attr('name').replace('mytr','');
            alert(key);
            obj[key]=null;
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Use a prompt `var name = prompt('Name?'); alert(name);` or build your own dialog using DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a named group use `prompt` instead of `confirm`. This will open a popup where the user can enter a group name. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eMXuZ/2/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn2',function () {
    var creat_group = prompt("Name your group??");
    if (creat_group) {
        console.log(obj);

        $("#groupsTable").append('<tr id="groupTr' + groupTrCount + '"></tr>');
        $tr=$("#groupTr" + groupTrCount);
        $tr.append("<td >" + creat_group + "</td>");
        var userColumn = "<ul>";
        $('#mytable tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
            var count=0;
            $(this).find('td').each(function() {
                if(count == 1){

                    userColumn+= "<li>" + $(this).html() + "</li>" ;
                }
                count++;
                });
        });
        userColumn+="<ul>";
        $tr.append("<td >" +userColumn+ "</td>");
    groupTrCount++;
    }        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `groupTrCount` only as the column text so you are getting the 0, 1... as indexes. You can try something like this

```
$tr.append("<td >Group: " + groupTrCount + "</td>");
```

instead of

```
$tr.append("<td >" + groupTrCount + "</td>");

$("#groupsTable").append('<tr id="groupTr' + groupTrCount + '"></tr>');
    $tr=$("#groupTr" + groupTrCount);
    $tr.append("<td >Group:" + groupTrCount + "</td>"); // or you can use whatever name you want in place of "Group:"
    var userColumn = "<ul>";
    $('#mytable tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
      var count=0;
      $(this).find('td').each(function() {
         if(count == 1){
        userColumn+= "<li>" + $(this).html() + "</li>" ;
         }
         count++;
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

For using the custom popup either you can made it by having a separate div on your page. Make it like an `overlay` with the help of `CSS`. Or you can easily do thi with [JQUERY UI DIALOGUE](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Comment: when you click on group then it will ask for group and after entering the group name then it will create group.Please tell me how to enter the group name

Comment: with javascript confirm you can not do it for doing so you need to make a custom popup window, where you can put a textbox for asking the Group name and then save it...

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use custom popup window?

Comment: you can easily do this with jquery UI dialog see here http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

Update Fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/175/

```
var val = 0;
var groupTrCount = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj={};
    $('#btn1').click(function () {
        if ($(".span4").val() != "") {
            $("#mytable").append('<tr id="mytr' + val + '"></tr>');
            $tr=$("#mytr" + val);
            $tr.append('<td class=\"cb\"><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"yes\" name="mytr' + val + '" checked ></td>');
            $(".span4").each(function () {
                $tr.append("<td >" + $(this).val() + "</td>");
            });
            var arr={};
            name=($tr.find('td:eq(1)').text());
            email=($tr.find('td:eq(2)').text());
            mobile=($tr.find('td:eq(3)').text());
            arr['name']=name;arr['email']=email;arr['mobile']=mobile;
            obj[val]=arr;
            val++;
        } else {
            alert("please fill the form completely");
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#btn2',function () {
        var creat_group = confirm("Do you want to creat a group??");
        if (creat_group) {
            console.log(obj);

            $tr.append("<td >" + groupTrCount + "</td>");

$("#groupsTable").append('<tr id="groupTr' + groupTrCount + '"></tr>');
    $tr=$("#groupTr" + groupTrCount);
    $tr.append("<td >Group:" + groupTrCount + "</td>"); // or you can use whatever name you want in place of "Group:"
    var userColumn = "<ul>";
    $('#mytable tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
      var count=0;
      $(this).find('td').each(function() {
         if(count == 1){
        userColumn+= "<li>" + $(this).html() + "</li>" ;
         }
         count++;
    });
});;
            userColumn+="<ul>";
            $tr.append("<td >" +userColumn+ "</td>");
        groupTrCount++;
        }        
    });
    $(document).on('change','#mytable input:checkbox',function () {
        if(!this.checked)
        {
            key=$(this).attr('name').replace('mytr','');
            alert(key);
            obj[key]=null;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: name should be user entered,tell me how to do?